# Angular 7 Routing giving me a ; in params

Tags: angular, angular7-router

I am trying to build this url **"table-screen?get=collaborator_list_admin"** but I am getting the following url **"table-screen;get=collaborator_list_admin"**

```
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    // code......
    // more code.......
    this.router.navigate(['table-screen', {get: 'collaborator_list_admin'}]);
```

Comment: Edited to remove AngularJS tag, AngularJS is a different framework

Answer (score 0):

this.router.navigate(['table-screen'], {queryParams:{get: 'collaborator_list_admin'}})